# iOS - NSData to UTF-8 html string

Tags: html, ios, utf-8, uiwebview, blob

The string stored in sqlite database with type blob. I read the data by NSData and try to get NSString from it. The string is Vietnamese string, i think it encode by UTF-8.
My Function:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ; -> Return nil

NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]; -> return nil
```

I try to replace encoding type by each of all type and with NSASCIIStringEncoding I get string i think It's the nearest the string I want.
The string is HTML string, i show it in the UIWebview.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../images/dic.css"><div class="m5t" id="mtd_0"><div class="p10l ovf"><div><div class="w fl">absolve</div><div class="p5l fl cB">[Éb'zÉlv]</div></div></div><div><div class="p10"><div id="partofspeech_0"><div class="ub"><span>ngoáº¡i Äá»ng tá»«</span></div><div class="m"><span> ( </span><a href="to">to</a> <a href="absolve">absolve</a> <a href="somebody">somebody</a> <a href="from">from</a> <span> / </span><a href="on">on</a> <a href="something">something</a> <span>) bÃ o chá»¯a cho ai khá»i bá» tá»i; tuyÃªn bá» ngÆ°á»i nÃ o khÃ´ng bá» trÃ¡ch cá»© hoáº·c khÃ´ng bá» rÃ ng buá»c vÃ o má»t lá»i há»©a, má»t nghÄ©a vá»¥; xoÃ¡ tá»i, miá»n trÃ¡ch</span></div><div class="e"><a href="to">to</a> <a href="absolve">absolve</a> <a href="someone">someone</a> <a href="from">from</a> <a href="blame">blame</a> </div><div class="em"><span> miá»n trÃ¡ch ai, tuyÃªn bá» ai khÃ´ng cÃ³ lá»i</span></div><div class="e"><a href="t"o>to</a> <a href="be">be</a> <a href="absolved">absolved</a> <a href="from">from</a> <a href="the">the</a> <a href="guilt">guilt</a> </div><div class="em"><span> ÄÆ°á»£c tuyÃªn Ã¡n vÃ´ tá»i</span></div><div class="e"><a href="the">the</a> <a href="court">court</a> <a href="absolved">absolved</a> <a href="the">the</a> <a href="accused">accused</a> <a href="man">man</a> <span> (</span><a href="from">from</a> <a href="all">all</a> <a href="responsibility">responsibility</a> <a href="for">for</a> <a href="her">her</a> <a href="death">death</a> <span>)</span></div><div class="em"><span> toÃ  tuyÃªn bá» ngÆ°á»i ÄÃ n Ã´ng bá» cÃ¡o khÃ´ng cÃ³ tá»i (khÃ´ng chá»u trÃ¡ch nhiá»m gÃ¬ vá» cÃ¡i cháº¿t cá»§a cÃ´ áº¥y)</span></div><div class="m"><span> tuyÃªn bá» tha cho ai</span></div><div class="e"><a href="to">to</a> <a href="absolve">absolve</a> <a href="repentant">repentant</a> <a href="sinners">sinners</a> </div><div class="em"><span> tha tá»i cho nhá»¯ng káº» cÃ³ tá»i nhÆ°ng ÄÃ£ Än nÄn</span></div></div></div></div></div>`
```

String show in UIWebview is the same the string above.
Sorry, I don't post image. Please help me.